# Matplotlib Basemap install issues mac OS

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to install basemap on my Mac.  I followed the steps listed here:
https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html#installation

Everything seemed to go well until I tried to test the install by typing into the python prompt:

```
>>>from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
ImportError: No module named axes_grid1
```

I saw another post that suggested updating matplot lib with:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I tried that to no avail. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

```
pip install --upgrade --user matplotlib numpy pyproj pyshp OWSLib Pillow
sudo apt install libgeos-dev
pip install --user --upgrade basemap-1.2.0rel.tar.gz
```

I have recently used the instructions above to update basemap on Ubuntu 18.04. I am not sure about the equivalent for macOS though. The basemap archive can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/releases).